# Download excel file with Selenium (Python) In Jenkins

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, jenkins

I'm facing a problem with **Selenium** in **Jenkins**. I have a scenario where I need to download a file by clicking a button. Despite the file being successfully downloaded (as verified by checking the Chrome downloads page using the URL chrome://downloads), I'm unable to locate the downloaded file in the specified download directory or any other directory. It seems like Selenium is not placing the downloaded file in the expected location.
How can I find the file?

```
context.driver_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    context.driver_options.add_argument('--incognito')
    context.driver_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    context.driver_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

    # Set download preferences
    path = os.path.abspath("Datasets/app_datasets")

    context.driver_options.add_experimental_option("prefs",
                                                   {"download.default_directory": path,
                                                          "download.prompt_for_download": False,
                                                          "download.directory_upgrade": True,
                                                          "safebrowsing.enabled": False,
                                                          "safebrowsing.disable_download_protection": True})
    # Set up capabilities
    context.capabilities = {
        "browserName": "chrome",
        "browserVersion": "117.0",
        "selenoid:options": {"enableVNC": True, "enableVideo": False}
    }

    # Create the WebDriver
    context.driver = webdriver.Remote(
        command_executor="http://localhost:4444/wd/hub",
        desired_capabilities=context.capabilities,
        options=context.driver_options
    )
```